# Solving Convex Optimization Problem Used for High Quality Denoising

Tags: noise, denoising, smoothing, convex-optimization

The highest voted answer to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/bag-of-tricks-for-denoising-signals-while-maintaining-sharp-transitions) suggests that to denoise a signal while preserving sharp transitions one should

> minimize the objective function:
>
> $$ |x-y|^2 + b|f(y)| $$
>
> where $x$ is the noisy signal, $y$ is the denoised signal, $b$ is the
>   regularziation parameter, and $|f(y)|$ is some L1 norm penalty.
>   Denoising is accomplished by finding the solution $y$ to this
>   optimization problem, and $b$ depends on the noise level.

However, there is no indication of how one might accomplish that in practice as that is a problem in a *very* high dimensional space, especially if the signal is e.g. 10 million samples long. In practice how is this sort of problem solved computationally for large signals?

Comment: Are you concerned with run time?  Otherwise, the iterature on how to minimize a function is quite extensive (Levenberg-Marquardt, Nelder-Mead, etc. come to mind).  There are even some modified versions that are made specifically for this.

Comment: Actually, I have a question for the people answering below.  Besides being slow, what is wrong with just something like Levenberg-Marquardt or Nelder-Mead?  These are generalized optimizers, so you can even numerically approximate $f$.

Comment: Yes, I am concerned with run time, but thanks for pointing these methods out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boyd has [A Matlab Solver for Large-Scale ℓ1-Regularized Least Squares Problems](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/l1_ls/l1_ls_usrguide.pdf). The problem formulation in there is slightly different, but the method can be applied for the problem.

[Classical majorization-minimization approach](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/teaching/lecture_notes/sparse_signal_restoration.pdf) also works well. This corresponds to iteratively perform soft-thresholding ([for TV, clipping](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/teaching/lecture_notes/TV_filtering.pdf)).

The solutions can be seen from the links. However, there are many methods to minimize these functionals by the extensive use of optimisation literature.

PS: As mentioned in other comments, FISTA will work well. Another 'very fast' algorithm family is primal-dual algorithms. You can see the [interesting paper of Chambolle](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/preprint/repository/685.pdf) for an example, however there are plethora of research papers on primal-dual methods for linear inverse problem formulations.

Comment: What does 'primal-dual' refer to exactly?

Comment: Mohammad, I did not implement any primal-dual algorithm for inverse problems. However, you can see an example from the link I mentioned in the answer: the paper of Chambolle. From this paper, you can see what a primal-dual algorithm means precisely. These methods provide just another (and fastly convergent) solution to inverse problems.

Comment: I thought primal dual is combinatorial optimization?  How can you transform this problem generically (for a generic $f$) into that framework?

Comment: thang, as I mentioned before, I am not an expert on this domain. You can see the paper of Chambolle and see that how primal-dual methods can be used to solve the problems like $\ell_1$ or TV regularization.

Answer (score 5):

To solve optimization problems with TV penalty, we use a recently proposed algorithm called [Fast Gradient Based Algorithms for Constrained Total Variation Image Denoising and Deblurring Problems (FISTA)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5173518), which has better convergence rate than conventional iterative methods, such as ASD-POCS.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add some more information on the algorithm, since the only reference you linked requires purchasing the article?

Comment: http://iew3.technion.ac.il/~becka/papers/71654.pdf

Comment: @JasonR, It is basically Nesterov Acceleration of the `Prox` operator. Really nice work.

Answer (score 4):

In the particular case where $f(y)=\|y\|_1$, the objective function can be written as

$$
\|x-y\|^2 + b\|y\|_1 = \sum_i(x_i - y_i)^2 + b\sum_i |y_i|,
$$

minimizing it requires to minimize each entry of the sum:

$$
\hat{y_i} = argmin \{(x_i-y_i)^2 + b|y_i|\}
$$

Using subdifferentials it is possible to show that the minimizer is the soft-thresholding operator with threshold $b$. That's the method proposed by Donoho and Johnstone for signal denoising. See their paper [Ideal spatial adaptation by wavelet shrinkage](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/81/3/425) for more details.

So in this case, I think that you don't need a more sophisticated solver to estimate your signal.

Comment: You have an $L^1$ norm penalty $\vert y_i\vert$ rather than a total variation penalty $\vert y_{i+1}-y_i\vert$. Is that a typo?

Comment: In the question it says: "and |f(y)| is some L1 norm penalty", so I just plugged the $\ell_1$ norm, which is   the classic case in signal denoising. But may be I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Yah, that could have been more clear. In that quote $f$ is a function on the entire signal, not necessarily a function being run on each component of the signal, that is $f$ can combine different signal samples together e.g. $f(x_0,x_1,...)=(x_1-x_0,x_2-x_1,...)$ is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: I see. I will add that my answer if for the particular case where $f(y)$ is the $\ell_1$ norm.

Answer (score 3):

Added: if $f(x) = \ell_1(x) = \sum |x_i|$, the terms are all independent —
as @Alejandro points out, you can just minimize each term by itself.
It's more interesting to minimize
    $\qquad\qquad$ $\| Ax - b \|_2^2 + \lambda \|x\|_1 $
where $\|x\|_1$ instead of $\|x\|_2$
is intended to push many $x_i$ to 0.
The following notes are for this case.
(I call the variables $x$, not $y$.)

---

(A year later) another name for this for the case $f(x) = \ell_1$ norm is
[Elastic net regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization).
Hastie et al.,
[Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn) 
p. 661 ff. discuss this for classification.

A fast simple way to get an approximate solution with many $x_i = 0$ is to alternate

1. minimize $\|Ax - b\|$ by plain least squares
2. shrink a.k.a. soft-threshold: set small $x_i = 0$.

This is a form of [Iteratively reweighted least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRLS), with weights 0 or 1.
I'd expect that methods in papers cited in previous answers will give better results; this is simple.

(When minimizing a sum $f() + \lambda g()$,
it's a good idea to plot $f()$ and $\lambda g()$ on a log-log scale for iter 1 2 3 ...
Otherwise, one term may swamp the other, and you won't even notice —
especially when they scale differently.)